# A sufficient condition for attaching  squares to a 1 skeleton so that the CW-complex is a 2 - manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cw-complexes, graph-theory

Suppose we have a finite connected graph $G$, I want to add 2 -cells to $G$ so that the 2 cells have boundaries of length 4 (squares)  and so that $G$ is the 1 skeleton of a surface (2-manifold) without boundary. To check that such a process can be done to $G$ does it suffice to check whether each edge in $G$ occurs as an edge of 2 distinct 4 -cycles? does it suffice to check if each edge occurs as exactly 2 distinct 4 cycles? Is there a known sufficient condition?

Comment: No, that won't suffice.  What you need to check is primarily at the vertices.  If a 2-cell is incident to a vertex, it gives an ordering of the two edges that it is incident to at that vertex.  What you need is that this gives a cyclic ordering of the edges incident.  In principle, you could have a non-cyclic ordering, for example, you could have two disjoint cycles.  This is what you'd get if you wedged two planar graphs together along a common vertex. 

Comment: @Ryan, Do you know of a sufficient condition so that this process can be done?

Comment: What I mentioned is a necessary and sufficient condition.  The edge condition that you mention is a consequence of the vertex condition I describe in my original comment. 